# Retrieve Database name from an variable

Tags: sql-server

I have a simple requirement where I need to replace a variable with the database name coming from another table.

I have a table called config setting

Key            value

ClubcardDB    ClubardDetailsDB

Code

```
Declare @Value varchar(100)
select @Value= value configsetting where Code=’ ClubcardDB’
Select top 10 * from  [@Value].[dbo].[ClubcardDetails]
```

it is giving an error: 
Invalid object name **'@Value.dbo.ClubcardDetails'.**

I do not want to build and dynamic query..

Comment: You would need dynamic sql for this.

Comment: Why did not you want to build dynamic query

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example that I made on my machine:

```
Declare @Value varchar(100)='Test'
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL='Select * from ' + QUOTENAME(@Value) + '.[sys].[all_columns];'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

A slightly safer method as it verifies the value is actually a database name:

```
Declare @Value varchar(100)='Test'
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL='Select * from ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.[sys].[all_columns];'
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
WHERE name=@Value

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: You'll want to at least handle SQL Injection here. This is just a security vulnerability as it is.

Comment: While that is true, if you can't control the value in your own configuration table, you have bigger issues.

Comment: I still suggest properly using `QUOTENAME` at least. A bracket can easily be escaped by someone malicious. For example `SET @Value = N'master].sys.objects; CREATE LOGIN t WITH PASSWORD=''1'',CHECK_POLICY=OFF,CHECK_EXPIRY=OFF;--'`

Comment: Really? What didn't work when you tried `'...FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@value) + '.sys...'`?

Comment: @Larnu I didn't remove the [] in the literal; answer updated

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `SQLCMD Mode`. In SSMS, click `Query -> SQLCMD Mode`:

```
:setvar dbname "YourDB" 

SELECT * FROM $(dbName).dbo.YourTable
```

[Read more about SQLCMD](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/sql-tools/the-sqlcmd-workbench/).